# I'm not executing anything and it's still saying Cannot close a connection while a transaction is still active

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I keep on getting this error and I'm not sure why. Here is the code. Im not even executing any sql and it's still saying "Cannot close a connection while a transaction is still active"

```
    DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
    int param = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("geoAreaID"));
    try (Connection tempConnection = DataAccess.OpenConnection())
    {
        tempConnection.rollback();
        tempConnection.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

        System.exit(e.getErrorCode());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(2);
    }
```

The DataAccess class has the method to open the connection, here it is.

```
    public static Connection OpenConnection() throws SQLException
{
    Properties tempConnectionProperties = new Properties();
    tempConnectionProperties.put("user", CONNECTION_USER);
    tempConnectionProperties.put("password", CONNECTION_PASSWORD);

    Connection tempConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING, tempConnectionProperties);

    tempConnection.setAutoCommit(true);
    tempConnection.createStatement().executeUpdate("SET SCHEMA APP");

    return tempConnection;

}
```

this is the full error message

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot close a connection while a transaction is still active.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.closeResourcesX(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.closeX(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.close(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.close(Unknown Source)
at dkaru.servlets.GeographicAreaServlet.doGet(GeographicAreaServlet.java:36)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: ERROR 25001: Cannot close a connection while a transaction is still active.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.checkForTransactionInProgress(Unknown Source)
... 29 more
```

Comment: `tempConnection.setAutoCommit(true);` does away with the need to commit or rollback

Comment: Always track down the **full** details of the exception you're getting from the database: https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: The code you show is leaking resources (the statement object created). It is also unnecessary to invoke `tempConnection.close()` as the try-with-resources will do that for you. Interestingly though given auto-commit is enabled (it is the default required by JDBC, so your code explicitly setting it is unnecessary), `tempConnection.rollback()` should throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the auto commit property of the connection worked for me. Code shown below :

```
conn.setAutoCommit(true);
```